# Serial port. BytesToRead() function

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am working with serial ports c#, CF 2.0

Can this function be trusted to return 0 when there is nothing to read?

```
while (_sp.BytesToRead > 0)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[255];
    int bytes_read = _sp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++)
    {
        value += buffer[i];
    }


}
ProcessValue(value);
```

what I want to do it read the data until there are no more bytes to read.
_sp is an instance of SerialPort class

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However, it may throw an exception - so be sure to handle that. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread.aspx).